# R inspect() function, from tm package, only returns 10 outputs when using dictionary terms

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining

I have 70 PDFs of scientific papers that I'm trying to narrow down by looking for specific terms within them, using the dictionary function of `inspect()`, which is part of the tm package. My PDFs are stored in a VCorpus object. Here's an example of what my code looks like using the crude dataset and common terms that would show up in (probably) every example paper in crude:

```
library(tm)
output.matrix <- inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(crude,
                                      list(dictionary = c("i","and",
                                                          "all","of",
                                                          "the","if",
                                                          "i'm","looking",
                                                          "for","but","because","has",
                                                          "it","was"))))
output <- data.frame(output.matrix)
```

This search only ever returns 10 papers into output.matrix. The outcome given is:

```
Docs  all and because but for has i i'm the was
  144   0   9       0   5   5   2 0   0  17   1
  236   0   7       4   2   4   5 0   0  15   7
  237   1  11       1   3   3   2 0   0  30   2
  246   0   9       0   0   6   1 0   0  18   2
  248   1   6       1   1   2   0 0   0  27   4
  273   0   5       2   2   4   1 0   0  21   1
  368   0   1       0   1   0   0 0   0  11   2
  489   0   5       0   0   4   0 0   0   8   0
  502   0   6       0   1   5   0 0   0  13   0
  704   0   5       1   0   3   2 0   0  21   0
```

For my actual dataset of 70 papers, I know there should be greater than 10 because as I add more PDFs to my VCorpus, which I know contain at least one of my search terms, I still only get 10 in the output. I want to adjust the outcome to be a list, like the one shown, that gives *every* paper from the VCorpus that contains a term, not just what I assume is the first 10.

Using R version 4.0.2, macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: From which package is `inspect`?

Comment: Please specify the package `tm` in your post

Comment: @starja tm, it was named in the body of the post but not the title, which has now been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what `inspect` does. For a document term matrix it show the first 10 rows and columns. `inspect` should only be used to check your corpus or document term matrix if it looks as you expect. Never for transforming data to a data.frame. If you want the data of the document term matrix in a data.frame, the following piece of code does this, using your example code and removing all the rows and columns that don't have a value for any of the documents or terms.

```
# do not use inspect as this will give a wrong result!
output.matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude,
                                    list(dictionary = c("i","and",
                                                        "all","of",
                                                        "the","if",
                                                        "i'm","looking",
                                                        "for","but","because","has",
                                                        "it","was")))


# remove rows and columns that are 0 staying inside a sparse matrix for speed
out <- output.matrix[slam::row_sums(output.matrix) > 0,
                     slam::col_sums(output.matrix) > 0]


# transform to data.frame
out_df <- data.frame(docs = row.names(out), as.matrix(out), row.names = NULL)

out_df
   docs all and because but for. has the was
1   127   0   1       0   0    2   0   5   1
2   144   0   9       0   5    5   2  17   1
3   191   0   0       0   0    2   0   4   0
4   194   1   1       0   0    2   0   4   1
5   211   0   2       0   0    2   0   8   0
6   236   0   7       4   2    4   5  15   7
7   237   1  11       1   3    3   2  30   2
8   242   0   3       0   1    1   1   6   1
9   246   0   9       0   0    6   1  18   2
10  248   1   6       1   1    2   0  27   4
11  273   0   5       2   2    4   1  21   1
12  349   0   2       0   0    0   0   5   0
13  352   0   3       0   0    0   0   7   1
14  353   0   1       0   0    2   1   4   3
15  368   0   1       0   1    0   0  11   2
16  489   0   5       0   0    4   0   8   0
17  502   0   6       0   1    5   0  13   0
18  543   0   0       0   0    3   0   5   1
19  704   0   5       1   0    3   2  21   0
20  708   0   0       0   0    0   0   0   1
```

Comment: This works for transforming the matrix to a dataframe, but I am looking for a solution to only getting 10 outputs. If ```inspect``` only shows the first 10 rows and columns, what should I use to pull out all of the documents out of my 70 that contain at least one of the given phrases?

Comment: @millie0725, If this is not what your are looking for, please create an expected output using the crude dataset.

Comment: I updated my original example code above to include an expected output with the crude dataset.